# Is it possible to have bash script output multiple lines over the same lines without 'clear'?

Tags: bash, unix

Bash script which outputs some stats.

```
while : 
do
      date
      sensors | grep "temp1"
      sensors | grep "Core"
      acpi
      sleep 1
done
```

It's possible to have one liner, like `date` and output it over and over the same line using `echo -ne "$(date)\r"`. Is it possible to do same with more than one line without using `clear`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you can do it:

```
while true; do    
    date
    sensors | grep "temp1"
    sensors | grep "Core"
    acpi

    sleep 1

    for i in {1..4}; do # clear four lines above
        tput cuu1 # up by one line
        tput el # clear that line
    done
done
```

Use `man tput` for more info. To see the list of capabilities use `man terminfo`

#### Edit:

Here is a hack that I came up with to avoid blinking:

```
while true; do
    echo -n "$(date)"; tput el; echo
    echo -n "$(sensors | grep "temp1")"; tput el; echo
    echo -n "$(sensors | grep "Core")"; tput el; echo
    echo -n "$(acpi)"; tput el; echo

    sleep 1
    tput cuu 4
    # tput -S <<< $'cuu1 \n cuu1 \n cuu1 \n cuu1' # that's how you pass several actions to tput, but instaed of cuu1 several times use 'cuu N'
done
```

And of course, this is going to work only if your commands output only one line.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you.
I tried without `tput el`, so now there's no blinking when data changes.

Comment: @user1347582 yes but without ``el`` it may leave some text from previous outputs. But with ``tput`` the possibilities are endless, so you might want to read the manual :)

Comment: @user1347582: (and Aleks) To avoid blinking, you want to use `tput el` after the output, not before you do the output; for example, `printf %s%s\\n "$(sensors | grep temp1)" "$(tput el)"`

Answer (score 4):

One option is to run it under [GNU watch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_%28Unix%29)

```
watch -n 1 'date; sensors | grep "temp1" ;sensors | grep "Core";acpi'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have:

```
echo -n $'\e[H\e[2J'
```

Or

```
tput clear
```